# How to execute .sql file in SQL server 2000/2005/2008

Tags: sql-server

When get a .sql file, how do you execute it? Double click to open it and press F5? Is there any other way to execute it and also able to see the execution result. Thanks.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

run the [OSQL](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa213090(SQL.80).aspx) or [SqlCmd](http://www.sqlcmd.org/) tools

for example

```
osql -D db_name -S server_name -U username -P password -i sqlfile
or
sqlcmd -D db_name -S server_name -U username -P password -i sqlfile
```

or you can use -E instead of user and password to do integrated security